# Simple aplication runs in phone not in emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I just installed all the things to develope for android with eclipse. 
I made a simple application.
I run it in my Phone and it looks like working.
I tryed to run it in the emulator but It show me this long text in the console.
Thanks for your time

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doSyncApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:871)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.syncApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:844)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.clientChanged(AndroidLaunchController.java:1487)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:868)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:398)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:835)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleAPNM(HandleAppName.java:90)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleChunk(HandleAppName.java:64)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:322)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

[2011-09-19 14:51:39 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doSyncApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:871)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.syncApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:844)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.clientChanged(AndroidLaunchController.java:1487)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:868)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:398)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:835)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleAPNM(HandleAppName.java:90)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleChunk(HandleAppName.java:64)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:322)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

[2011-09-19 14:56:00 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doSyncApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:871)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.syncApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:844)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.clientChanged(AndroidLaunchController.java:1487)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:868)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:398)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:835)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleAPNM(HandleAppName.java:90)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleChunk(HandleAppName.java:64)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:322)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)








private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 800;
private Camera mCamera;

private Font mFont;
private Texture mFontTexture;


private ChangeableText textoOut;

@Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
     this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
     return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera));

}

@Override
public void onLoadResources() {

    // FUENTES
    this.mFontTexture = new Texture(512, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.mFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(this.mFontTexture, this, "font/Droid.ttf", 32, true, Color.BLACK);
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(this.mFontTexture);
    this.mEngine.getFontManager().loadFonts(this.mFont);




}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    final Scene scene = new Scene(1);
    scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));
    textoOut = new ChangeableText(50, 50, mFont,"Hola mundo");
    scene.attachChild(textoOut);


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return scene;
}

@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {


}
```

}

Comment: Unless you post your code, specifically pertaining to the lines where a NPE is thrown, we have no idea what is going on.